# jQuery not consistently resizing divs - Equal height divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page, I have 6 divs set up in two rows of three. I'm using a jQuery function to give them a height so that they are always the height of the div with the tallest content. When I load the page, sometimes this works, and sometimes it doesn't. Most of the time, it doesn't and the divs will be shorter than their content. Sometimes when I hit refresh, they will extend to be the height of the tallest div. I'm not sure what could be causing this. The function is inside of the document ready.

I should note that the jQuery function works on my local document consistently but not in GitHub.

Here is the site: http://amykirst.github.io/portfolio/

The divs are under "View My Work".

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // alert("document is ready!");
  applyHeight();
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
    $('.menu').toggleClass('open');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    applyHeight();
  });
}); // End document ready

// size samples to equal heights

// function to determine the tallest element
function equalHeight(block) {
  // Set tallest height to 0
  var tallest = 0;
  // Iterate over each block
  block.each(function() {
    // Creates variable and stores height for current element
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    // If current element's height is greater than 0 (or the tallest),      then it becomes the tallest
    if (thisHeight > tallest) {
      tallest = thisHeight;
    }
  });
   // Sets all block heights to the height of the tallest element
  block.height(tallest);
}

// function to apply equal heights
function applyHeight() {
  // If the sample is 300px wide run equal height function
  if ($(".sample").css("width") == "300px") {
    equalHeight($(".sample"));
    // If the sample is not 300px wide, set height to auto
  } else {
    $(".sample").css("height", "auto");
  }
}
```

Comment: $(window).load(function() {
      applyHeight();
});

Comment: That looks like it worked. Is it because the .load function loads all of the images first, where is the .ready function loads the DOM but not the images before the JS runs? Also, if you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function() { applyHeight(); });
```

**EDIT:**

- $(window).load() - fired after content loaded, including images.
- After images load, then you can count height

Comment: This answer desperately needs some explanation.  Why it works, where to put it...

Comment: @KirkRoybal amylynn83 is itself explained in the commentary questions

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready()` fires as soon as the DOM is loaded, even if images aren't. For this, you'll need to wait until all of the content is loaded. `$(window).load()` does that:

```
$(window).load(applyHeight);
```

(I pass the `applyHeight` function as the parameter for simplicity.)

Answer (score 0):

```
equalheight = function(container){

var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;
 $(container).each(function() {

   $el = $(this);
   $($el).height('auto')
   topPostion = $el.position().top;

   if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
     }
     rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
     currentRowStart = topPostion;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);
   } else {
     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
  }
   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
   }
 });
}

$(window).load(function() {
  equalheight('.main article');
});


$(window).resize(function(){
  equalheight('.main article');
});
```